# Class 'Pusher' not found on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, caching, shared-hosting, pusher

I recently uploaded my laravel app to shared hosting. I know it is not recommended, but still.

When I upload it I get an error like this

[image]

I installed `pusher/pusher-php-server` using composer. 
It is working fine on localhost
Is that a problem of any cache? I tried deleting cache under `/bootstrap/cache` and inside `/storage`. But no use.

I found that `/bootstrap/cache/config.php` file is not generating by laravel when it is hosted.

And I also didn't forgot to upload the `/vendor/pusher/pusher-php-server` folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to tell composer to reindex installed packages:

`composer dump-autoload`

Comment: can you tell me running this command will affect which all files? So that I can upload it individually to server.

Comment: @Conor, you don't need to upload them manually. It will just re-index list of  all files needed to be included in your project. Like If you create some file within your project and want laravel to know that its there. You run this command.

Read on here http://developed.be/2014/08/29/composer-dump-autoload-laravel/

Comment: In your case, you added Pusher library to your project. Which laravel needs to know that it is there before it can use `Pusher`. Hope it helps

Comment: @NaumanZafar I don't have any problem with it on localhost. But when I look at the server I find error. After running this code I tried to upload `/vendor/autoload.php` file to the server then a new error pops up -- `Fatal error: Class 'ComposerAutoloaderInit280c85c9a3d91a64fb63e6119a63242a' not found in /home/u265837639/vendor/autoload.php on line 7`